# Is there a shortcut for repeat the second proximate command in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-history

We all know that `!!` can repeat the last command you do in bash.

But sometimes we need to do some operation like

```
$ python test.py
$ vim test.py

$ python test.py # here is where I need to repeat the second proximate bash command
```

I can use up-arrow key to do that, but that requires me to move my right hand away to an uncomfortable position. So I'm wondering if there is a command which like `!!` would work?

Comment: Use `Ctrl+P` in emacs mode (default), or `k` in vi-mode if you don't want to reach for the up key.

Comment: I’d actually write both commands in one line like `vim test.py && python test.py` to avoid fiddling with multiple commands in history, but you can simply bind `"\ep": previous-history` in your `~/.inputrc` so you could press Alt+p instead of up key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`!-2`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators):

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo bar
bar
$ !-2
echo foo
foo
```

That may not help with your right-hand situation.

You can also use [`!string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) history searching for this sort of case:

```
$ python test.py
$ vim test.py
$ !py
python test.py # Printed, then run
```

This may be more convenient to use. It will run:

> the most recent command preceding the current position in the history list starting with *string*.

Even just `!p` would work. You can use `!?string` to search the whole command line, rather than just the start.

Comment: It's much better! since arrow keys needs to move your entire wrist, and !-2 only requires finger movements, excellent, Michael. Wow, just read the second part, it's out of my expectation. You are a magician!

Comment: You can also perform on-the-fly history expansion on what you've typed by using Bash's "history-expand-line" Alt+^ or "shell-expand-line" Alt+Ctrl+e (also aliases) to expand designators/modifiers and check before you go pressing Enter.  So, for example, if you had `echo Hello World!` back four lines in the history and typed

    echo !-4

then Alt-^ you'll get the expansion of the `!-4` immediately and see

    echo Hello World

expanded ready and waiting.

Find out more about those designators and modifiers in the man page for Bash look for "Event Designators" to start with.

Answer (score 4):

```
!-2
```

More fun is available. Say you want to keep operating on a file (as above, where you're using test.py, repeatedly):

```
cp foo.py thing.py
edit $_
python $_
!-2
^thing^foo
```

- Copy an existing file to `thing.py`
- Edit (vim, emacs - though why you'd be using a command line if you were running Emacs-OS, I have no idea) `thing.py` - the last word in the previous command line
- `python thing.py`
- Edit `thing.py`
- Edit `foo.py`

History manipulation is such fun. Try `man history`. Note that the quest to re-use history can result in typing far more than the command itself would. The final command substitution, where I replace thing.py by foo.py is one such example. Fewer characters to just type in the command and name. :)

The history substitution is also why you get strange messages when you try:

```
$ echo "This is a disaster!"
-bash: !": event not found
```

The exclamation mark is being consumed as a history reference, and it can't find a previous command with a double quote.

Comment: By the way, If I got echo 'xxx', how do I substitute each 'x' into 'y'?

Comment: Substituting a string for another string? Just that? `!!:1gs/x/y/`

Comment: Though personally, I'd be looking at `$(echo !! | sed -e s/x/y/g)`

Comment: using sed would be too clumsy, can I add some parameter or symbol in ^x^y to do that job?